# VS2013: "Match Case" always defaults to checked in Find and Replace Dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm not sure when it started happening or how (though it may have coincided with VS2013 Update 4), but for some reason, every time I start VS2013 and go to the "Find and Replace" dialog (Ctrl-Shift-F), "Match Case" under the "Find Options" is checked. Previously, the option was either unchecked or at worst was "sticky" - meaning it retained the previous selection across runs of VS2013.

[image: Find and Replace Dialog]

I can un-check it and run a search, and it stays un-checked as long as that instance of Visual Studio is running, but the next time I start VS2013, it's checked again. Can't find any obvious setting under Tools | Options.

Comment: Still hoping to find a solution to this issue, by the upvotes I'm guessing I'm not the only one who's seeing it...

Comment: @Cliff-Mayson See my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a hunch (and thanks to the gentle prodding from @Cliff Mayson, I decided to search through the registry to see if there was any obvious setting that was forcing case-sensitive searching in VS2013. Didn't take long to find the answer:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Find\DialogOptions
```

had a value of

```
MatchCase=1 WholeWord=0 Hidden=1 Up=0 Selection=0 Block=0 KeepCase=0 SubFolders=1 KeepOpen=1 NameOnly=0 Plain Solution FindAll
```

I changed `MatchCase=1` to `MatchCase=0` and restarted VS2013. Voila! No more case-sensitive search!

There are some other similar-looking registry keys in that section but I didn't mess with any of them.

Answer (score 6):

To complete a bit more. The registry key that Mr. T's refers to applies to the classic Find dialog but not to the new smaller and embedded one that VS2013 has. But you will get the same effect with that one too by changing the MatchCase value of the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Find\AdornmentOptions
```

which is two rows above DialogOptions from

```
MatchCase=1
```

to

```
MatchCase=0
```

I.e., just as it is done for the DialogOptions key.